# Download a database file to the app directory

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i want to update the sqlite database of the app when clicking on a button using the DownloadManager.

But it says "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a file URI: /data/user/0/com.example.laudien.listviewtesting/databases/Employees"

What do i make wrong? Do i need a permission for that? The internet permission is already in the manifest.

Here is the code of my updateDb() method:

```
private void updateDb() {
    DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE); // create download manager
    DownloadFinishedReceiver receiver = new DownloadFinishedReceiver(); // create broadcast receiver
    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE)); // register the receiver
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(DATABASE_URL)); // create a download request

    // delete database file if it exists
    File databaseFile = new File(getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getAbsolutePath());
    if(databaseFile.exists())
        databaseFile.delete();

    request//.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_HIDDEN) // not visible
        .setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI) // only via wifi
        .setDestinationUri(Uri.parse("file:" + getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getAbsolutePath())); // set path in app dir
    downloadManager.enqueue(request); // enqueue the download request
}
```

Comment: Hey ! Why don't you directly reuse databaseFile URI's directly ? Namely, databaseFile.toURI(); into the setDestinationUri() method.

In addition, if you had a permission problem, you'd get a SecurityException. I've quickly adapted and tried your example to download Google's logo and it worked pretty fine. e.g. .setDestinationUri(Uri.parse("file:" + Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+ "/google.png"))

Comment: Thank you for your response! I tried .setDestinationUri(databaseFile.toURI()) but then it says "android.net.Uri" cannot be applied to "java.net.Uri". 

Then I tried .setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(databaseFile)) but it says "java.lang.SecurityException: Unsupported path /data/user/0/com.example.laudien.listviewtesting/databases/Employees"

Then i added the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions and accepted it in the emulator, but it is the same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your path `/data/user/0/com.example.laudien.listviewtesting` is private internal memory of your app. You obtained it using `getFilesDir()`. Other apps have no access. Including the download manager. Use external memory given by `getExternalStorageDirectory()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who wants to download sensitive files to app's *private folders*, I have to say that *download manager* doesn't have access to these folders inside internal storage.
But the solution is moving the downloaded file in *broadcast receiver*.
For example putting such line in ***BroadcastReceiver***:

```
String destinationFileName = "test.mp4";
String filePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));
copyFile(Uri.parse(filePath).getPath(), context.getFilesDir() + "/" + destinationFileName);
```

and *copyFile* is a method like this:

```
private void copyFile(String inFileName, String outFileName) throws IOException {

    InputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(inFileName);

    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    // Transfer bytes from the input file to the output file
    byte[] myBuffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(myBuffer)) > 0)
        myOutput.write(myBuffer, 0, length);

    // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}
```

Comment: What is `cursor`?

Comment: @Starwave I use a cursor to read a specific COLUMN_* constant from the result of download => Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query(new DownloadManager.Query());