# How store Downloaded file using DownloadManager to app's files directory allocated?

Tags: android, directory, store, download-manager, file-uri

I am trying to store downloaded file using DownloadManager to app/s files  directory allocated by android.For this i am using following code

```
downloadManager=(DownloadManager)getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(link);
    DownloadManager.Request request= new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false);
    request.setTitle(fileName);

    File file = ctx.getFilesDir();
    Uri myPath=Uri.fromFile(file);
    request.setDestinationUri(myPath);

    Long reference= downloadManager.enqueue(request);
    Toast.makeText(DownloadActivity.this,"Downloading Started",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

By using this code i am getting following error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.puranepaper.PuranePaper, PID: 18263
java.lang.SecurityException: Unsupported path /data/data/com.puranepaper.PuranePaper/files
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2005)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:476)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1552)
    at android.app.DownloadManager.enqueue(DownloadManager.java:1163)
    at com.puranepaper.PuranePaper.DownloadActivity$1.onClick(DownloadActivity.java:92)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6310)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24970)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:171)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6654)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

How i can remove "Unsupported path" error and what i am doing wrong in this code

Answer (score 1):

Other apps (including the download manager) have no access to your app's internal memory.

Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39911001/download-a-database-file-to-the-app-directory).

Answer (score -1):

Start myPath with "file://"

request.setDestinationUri("file://" + myPath);

This works for me:

```
public void downloadFile(String address, String destination) {  
        ///// Baja el archivo a la carpeta indicada.
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(address);
        String Nombre = address.substring(address.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
        // request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI); // Solo WiFi.
           request.setDestinationUri(Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + destination  + "/"  + Nombre));
        // Bajada.
        DownloadManager downloadmanager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        downloadmanager.enqueue(request);
    }
```

downloadFile("http://example.com/myfile.jpg", "/mydirectory")

Comment: Explain your solution. It is a bad style just putting code without any explanation.